# jquery: Change image and POST to external page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little icon that when clicked I want to change to another little icon and also POST a number to another page (but ignore the HTML of the new page). The purpose is for a user to "favorite" a product. I can't get it to work though, nothing happens at all.

The code I'm using in the head is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.addlib').live("click",function() {
        var pibn = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/addlibrary.php",
            data: "pibn="+pibn, 
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('a.addlib').html('<img src="/images/icons/tick.png" width="18" height="18" class="iconbutton" />');
            },
            success: function(html) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and in the body:

```
<span id="1000915326" class="addlib"><a href="#"><img src="/images/icons/info.png" width="18" height="18" class="iconbutton" /></a></span>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i think .live is deprecated...so better to use .on

Answer (score 1):

```
beforeSend: function() {
   $('a.addlib').html('<img src="/images/icons/tick.png" width="18" height="18" class="iconbutton" />');
}
```

Replace it with

```
beforeSend: function() {
   $('span.addlib a').html('<img src="/images/icons/tick.png" width="18" height="18" class="iconbutton" />');
}
```

because `a.addLib` doesn't exists.

**Complete Tested Code.**

```
$(function() 
{
    $('.addlib').live("click",function()
    {
        var pibn       = $(this).attr("id");
        var clickedDom = $(this);
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/addlibrary.php",
            data: "pibn="+pibn, 
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                clickedDom.find('a').html('<img src="/images/icons/tick.png" width="18" height="18" class="iconbutton" />');
            },
            success: function(html)
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Would be even better to reference the element clicked via `this` inside the `click` handler

Comment: @Phil right but i just cleared point about where OP doing wrong...and this may not refer to clicked dom inside ajax as i personally experienced.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution

```
$(document).on('click', '.addlib', function() {
    var span = $(this),
        img = span.find('img');
    $.post('/addlibrary.php', {
        pibn: span.attr('id')
    }, function() {
        img.attr('src', img.attr('src').replace('info', 'tick'))
            .parent('a').unwrap();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Phil, it still doesn't work but I'm not sure why. I've put your code in the head and then in the body is: `<span id="1000002215" class="addlib"><a href="#" ><img src="/images/icons/info.png" width="18" height="18" class="iconbutton" /></a></span>` but nothing..?

Comment: Even changing everything inside that function to `alert("test")` does nothing either. So it's obviously not registering the click.

Comment: @Alasdair I'm guessing you're putting this code in the `<head>` and not in a `document.ready` handler. I've updated it to work anywhere